# Allow user to chose application for open file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

In application user can download file and open it after download completed.

I can open window for choosing application something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);                 
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But here "image/*" is hard-coded. In my application user can download files with different extensions (txt, gif, png, doc, .etc).

Of course I can do something like this:

```
if(fileExt.equels("png") || fileExt.equels("jpg")  || fileExt.equels("gif") )
   intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
```

But then i need to write code for all extensions =/

So, can you suggest better way to filter this file extensions?

Comment: if you know for a fact that the extension exists and is correct, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use activity chooser: (of course you need to provide MIME type as image/* so that only applications which can handle images will appear in the activity chooser.

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```